# App Store Connect Operation Error, "An error occurred while trying to start the iTMSTransporter"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, itunes, itmstransporter

[image]While uploading build I am getting an issue: "An error occurred while trying to start the iTMSTransporter"

XCode Version: 11.2 (11B52)
Mac Version: Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57).

I have tried to re-add my developer account to xcode, nothing works. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check your network connection and open your app store account in browser

Comment: This is not cause because of network issue , it xcode issue @Niravshekhaliya

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

Open the terminal and run the following command:

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```

This will force iTunes to recreate a new ~/.itmstransporter folder.

Solution 2:

Check if any updates are pending or not either iTunes or MacOs

Comment: @Naresh Have you tried with `Application Loader`? and also check with your internet if it isn't blocking

Answer (score 0):

After an huge R & d I get to know that the xcode 11.2 can't be used to upload TestFlight build. This is an issue with xcode.